# Error : Adding a Foreign key - insert or update on table "X" violates foreign key constraint "FK_X_Y_Z"

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I am trying to update a DB table with ForeignKey.

Inside the Departures I have "AirportCode" column.
Inside the Flights I have "DepartureAirportCode" column.
I trying to add DepartureAirportCode as a ForeignKey.

I got this error.

fail:

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
Failed executing DbCommand (213ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='300']
ALTER TABLE "Flight" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_Flight_Departures_DepartureAirportCode" FOREIGN KEY ("DepartureAirportCode") REFERENCES "Departures" ("AirportCode") ON DELETE CASCADE;
Failed executing DbCommand (213ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='300']
ALTER TABLE "Flight" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_Flight_Departures_DepartureAirportCode" FOREIGN KEY ("DepartureAirportCode") REFERENCES "Departures" ("AirportCode") ON DELETE CASCADE;
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23503: insert or update on table "Flight" violates foreign key constraint "FK_Flight_Departures_DepartureAirportCode"

**MessageText**:

**insert or update on table "Flight" violates foreign key constraint "FK_Flight_Departures_DepartureAirportCode"**
**Detail: Key (DepartureAirportCode)=() is not present in table "Departures".**

Update :  Resolved this issue. The issue on my database Departure Table's data.  Thank you

Comment: You have to post your classes if  you need some help

Comment: I have updated with classes.

Comment: Hi @hanushic, please share your model class and if you configure any relationship in dbcontext. Besides, please share what's the code you operate the database.

Answer (score 0):

Only primary key or alternate (or principal) Key can be used as a foreign key. I higly recommend you to use a Departure primary key Id as a foreign key. You can try to config an alternative key, but I can't see much sense to make your db structure much more complicated. If AirportCode changes in the future, you will have very big problems in db updating. This is why independent keys are used in the most databases.

```
public class Flight
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int? DepartureId{ get; set; }

        public Departure Departure { get; set; }
}
```

but if you still want the departure code in the flight, you don't need to mantain 2 keys. The easiest way is to make departure Code as primary one

```
public class Departure
    {
        [Key]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty(nameof(Flight.Departure))]
        public IEnumerable<Flight> Flights { get; set; }
    }

public class Flight
    {   [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string DepartureCode { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(DepartureCode))]
        [InverseProperty("Flights")]
        public virtual Departure Departure { get; set; }
}
```

you don't need this since you have the attibute annotations. but just in case

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Flight>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Departure)
                   .WithMany(p => p.Flights)
                   .HasForeignKey(d => d.DepartureCode);
            });
```

Comment: I tried as on this post https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/54799285/ef-core-join-using-include-but-foreignkey-is-not-primary-key-on-the-other-table. Foreignkey should not be a primary key of another table. 
I have update my question with DbContext. Plz check

Comment: @hanushic see my answer update

Comment: I want DepartureAirportCode as foreign key in Flight Table. You did ` [NotMapped] `. So It will not in my DB